# Converting and enriching an array of data

Tags: java

The method below converts an array of `TheatreListData` objects to an array of `TheatreListDataWrapper`. It also loads additional attributes such as `patientIdentifierNumber` and `requestText` to enrich the converted data.

This method is called by many EJBs, and so I'm especially looking for ways to improve performance.

```
/** 
* Converts TheatreListDatas into TheatreListDataWrappers. This also 
* loads the attributes that has to be generated from client such as 
* patientIdentifierNumber, requestText 
* 
* @param theatreListData 
* @return TheatreListDataWrapper[] 
*/
public TheatreListDataWrapper[] wrapData(TheatreListData[] theatreListData){

    TheatreListDataWrapper[] wrapperList = wrapDataWithoutRequestData(theatreListData);

    if (wrapperList != null && wrapperList.length > 0)
    {
      Set<String> requestIds = new HashSet<String>();

      for (TheatreListData listData : theatreListData)
      {

        // Collect request id for each List Data into a set
        String requestId = listData.getCarePlan().requestId;
        //Should check for '-1' here to avoid calls to fetch invalid requests.
        //'-1' could have been saved with registrations with 'None' requests.
        if (requestId != null && requestId.trim().length() > 0 && !requestId.equals("-1"))
        {
          //Since adding to a set no duplicates are possible.
          requestIds.add(requestId);
        }
      }

      //Load request Id, request Text map using the collected request ids.
      Map<String, String> requestMap = Collections.emptyMap();
      if (!requestIds.isEmpty())
      {
        requestMap = getRequestDelegator().getRequestPresentationStringsByIds(new ArrayList<String>(requestIds));
      }

      //Create wrappers & fill with loaded data.
      for (int i = 0; i < theatreListData.length; i++)
      {
        TheatreListDataWrapper wrapper = wrapperList[i];

        TheatreListData listData = theatreListData[i];
        String requestId = listData.getCarePlan().requestId;
        if (requestId != null && requestId.trim().length() > 0)
        {
          wrapper.requestText = requestMap.get(requestId) != null ? requestMap.get(requestId) : "";
        }

        wrapperList[i] = wrapper;
      }

    }
    return wrapperList;

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the constant overhead of retrieving the request presentation string for a request ID (i.e. is it considerably more efficient to get all the strings for a bunch of IDs at once than for each ID separately?), a better design might be to iterate over the theatre list only once, getting the representation strings as you go and caching the results in a Map.

```
Map<String, String> cache = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < theatreListData.length; i++) {
    TheatreListDataWrapper wrapper = wrapperList[i];
    TheatreListData listData = theatreListData[i];
    String requestId = listData.getCarePlan().requestId;
    if (validRequestId(requestId)) {
        String text = cache.get(requestId);
        if (text == null) {
            text = getRequestDelegator().getRequestPresentationStringsById(requestId);
            cache.put(requestId, text);
        }
        wrapper.requestText = text;
    }
}
```

This is probably not a good idea of getting the request text requires, say, a database query.

Other than that, I can think of no algorithmic improvements. You should store the result of `requestMap.get(requestId)` in a local variable so you don't do the call twice; that's inefficient. Perhaps you can modify `getRequestPresentationStringsByIds` to take a `Collection` instead of a `List` so that you don't have to wrap your set in an `ArrayList`. Can't think of more.

Answer (score 1):

If you're under Java 8 then I'd prefer using the Stream API:

```
theatreListData
    .stream()
    .map(listData -> listData.getCarePlan().requestId)
    .filter(id -> id != null)
    .filter(id -> id.trim().length() > 0)
    .filter(id -> !id.equals("-1"))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

And this comparsion never throws NPE.

```
"Constant".equals(variable);
```

Comment: Sorry mate. I'm in Java 7

Comment: Then I would define each "for" as new function